# How to find specific substrings (that can be very similar) and do different things with them in java

Tags: java, string, file, substring

I am writing a program that takes in a file and extracts data from a single string within the file. I run into a problem when I try to separate the substrings in the way that I want. The goal is to separate the larger chunks of the line from other large chunks without separating the smaller  chunks within the larger chunk (separated by commas).

An example of the file contents would be this: (Although it is slightly long, the files I have may vary from short lists like this to 50 or even to 100 blocks of item sets)

```
{"timeStamp":1477474644345,"itemSets":[{"mode":"any","sortrank":4999,"type":"custom","priority":false,"isGlobalForMaps":true,"uid":"LOL_D957E9EC-39E4-943E-C55E-52B63E05D99C","isGlobalForChampions":false,"associatedMaps":[],"associatedChampions":[40],"blocks":[{"type":"starting","items":[{"id":"3303","count":1},{"id":"2031","count":1},{"id":"1082","count":1},{"id":"3340","count":1},{"id":"3363","count":1},{"id":"2043","count":1},{"id":"3364","count":1}]},{"type":"Support Build Items","items":[{"id":"2049","count":1},{"id":"1001","count":1},{"id":"3165","count":1},{"id":"3117","count":1},{"id":"2301","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1},{"id":"3135","count":1},{"id":"3504","count":1}]},{"type":"AP Build Items","items":[{"id":"3165","count":1},{"id":"3020","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1},{"id":"3135","count":1},{"id":"3285","count":1},{"id":"3116","count":1}]},{"type":"Other Items (Situational Items)","items":[{"id":"3026","count":1},{"id":"3285","count":1},{"id":"3174","count":1},{"id":"3001","count":1},{"id":"3504","count":1}]}],"title":"Janna Items","map":"any"},{"mode":"any","sortrank":0,"type":"custom","priority":false,"isGlobalForMaps":false,"uid":"LOL_F265D25A-EA44-5B86-E37A-C91BD73ACB4F","isGlobalForChampions":true,"associatedMaps":[10],"associatedChampions":[],"blocks":[{"type":"Searching","items":[{"id":"3508","count":1},{"id":"3031","count":1},{"id":"3124","count":1},{"id":"3072","count":1},{"id":"3078","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1}]}],"title":"TEST","map":"any"}]}
```

The code I have attempted to write tries to separate this into meaningful chunks, here is what I have written so far:

```
        cutString = dataFromFile.substring(dataFromFile.indexOf("itemSets\":") + 11, dataFromFile.indexOf("},{"));
        stringContinue = dataFromFile.substring(cutString.length());
        while(stringContinue.contains("},{"))
        {
            //Do string manipulation to cut every part and re-attach it, then re-check to find if this ("},{\"id") is not there
            if(stringContinue.contains("},{\"id"))
            {
                //if(stringContinue.equals(anObject))
                cutString = cutString + stringContinue.substring(0, stringContinue.indexOf("},{\"id"));
            }
            else if(stringContinue.contains("},{\"count"))
            {
                cutString = cutString + stringContinue.substring(0, stringContinue.indexOf("},{\"count"));
            }
            else if(stringContinue.contains("},{"))
            {
                cutString = cutString + stringContinue.substring(0, stringContinue.indexOf("},{"));
            }

            stringContinue = stringContinue.substring(cutString.length());

            //Check if we see a string pattern that is the cut off point
            //if()
            //System.out.println(stringContinue);
            System.out.println(cutString);
        }
```

But when I run it, I get an output like this:

```
{"mode":"any","sortrank":4999,"type":"custom","priority":false,"isGlobalForMaps":true,"uid":"LOL_D957E9EC-39E4-943E-C55E-52B63E05D99C","isGlobalForChampions":false,"associatedMaps":[],"associatedChampions":[40],"blocks":[{"type":"starting","items":[{"id":"3303","count":1arting","items":[{"id":"3303","count":1
```

The output I want to achieve is this:

```
{"mode":"any","sortrank":4999,"type":"custom","priority":false,"isGlobalForMaps":true,"uid":"LOL_D957E9EC-39E4-943E-C55E-52B63E05D99C","isGlobalForChampions":false,"associatedMaps":[],"associatedChampions":[40],"blocks":[{"type":"starting","items":[{"id":"3303","count":1},{"id":"2031","count":1},{"id":"1082","count":1},{"id":"3340","count":1},{"id":"3363","count":1},{"id":"2043","count":1},{"id":"3364","count":1}]},{"type":"Support Build Items","items":[{"id":"2049","count":1},{"id":"1001","count":1},{"id":"3165","count":1},{"id":"3117","count":1},{"id":"2301","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1},{"id":"3135","count":1},{"id":"3504","count":1}]},{"type":"AP Build Items","items":[{"id":"3165","count":1},{"id":"3020","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1},{"id":"3135","count":1},{"id":"3285","count":1},{"id":"3116","count":1}]},{"type":"Other Items (Situational Items)","items":[{"id":"3026","count":1},{"id":"3285","count":1},{"id":"3174","count":1},{"id":"3001","count":1},{"id":"3504","count":1}]}],"title":"Janna Items","map":"any"}

{"mode":"any","sortrank":0,"type":"custom","priority":false,"isGlobalForMaps":false,"uid":"LOL_F265D25A-EA44-5B86-E37A-C91BD73ACB4F","isGlobalForChampions":true,"associatedMaps":[10],"associatedChampions":[],"blocks":[{"type":"Searching","items":[{"id":"3508","count":1},{"id":"3031","count":1},{"id":"3124","count":1},{"id":"3072","count":1},{"id":"3078","count":1},{"id":"3089","count":1}]}],"title":"TEST","map":"any"}
```

So then my question is how do I check for the point where I can separate the blocks without getting java to detect the same pattern that it uses to separate the smaller chunks? Basically I am looking for a pattern like this ("},{"), but not this ("},{\"id:") or this ("},{\count:"). Is there any other things that the String Class can offer for functionality that is similar that i am not aware of?

Edit: Although using a json parser would make things easier and convenient for this type of problem, another one rises because it would make the program only take in json files. This question is more for string manipulation and trying to find a part of the string that can separate the large blocks of information without touching or changing (very minimally as possible) the smaller blocks that have the same way of separation. So far regex and splitting strings to be re-attached later seems to be the way to go unless there is a more clear-cut answer.

Comment: You should use a json parser not substring

Comment: I wish to do it this way for more control over the code that it reads in, although it would have been simpler to use a parser (I am looking into it right now). I would need to read in this file to set variables in another part of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string into an array based on regex like this:

```
//fileString is the String you get from your file
String[] chunksIWant = fileString.split("\\},\\{");
```

This will return the String array `chunksIWant` split in the chunks you want. It does get rid of the regex itself, in this case `"},{"`, so if you would need the symbols for some reason you will have to add them back afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a shot.

Comment: I do apologize if this is taking me longer than expected. I was running into an error "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1" and I was trying to figure out what it means (since I have not used regex and the Split function before, and currently doing research on it).

Comment: Hmm, you are correct, I haven't used the split function before with the symbols `{}`, and after a bit of research they are apparently used by the regex itself for something specific, expecting a number, thus it's failing. Fault is on my side, am looking to find you a solution.

Comment: The symbols had to be escaped, by using `\\`, I edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, take your time, i will continue to research this topic as well seeing that this is an interesting way to solve this maybe.
Edit: now I see the edits, I had to refresh the page and now trying your solution, i will get back to you when something happens or if it works.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be what I was looking for. After many tests and tons of research, using regex seems to be the best to split it. All that is left is making cases and finding the chunks to put the smaller chunks back together. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this data from file in Json format.
So when you get that data on java side use JsonParser to convert data in JsonArray format.
Then you can iterate that JsonArray to get as JsonObject by using String name.
You can use value of JsonObject as required.